# background css issues - background cut on the wrong place

Tags: css, angular

I am working of background with css, and I have few isuus that I need to solve

1. the background cut on the lett and right (if I change it to "cover") it cut on the top and button
   2.the background is not full image, it cut in the buttom.
   the picture
   [with this css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6adO.png)
   css

```css
.grid-full[_ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c6] {
    background-image: url(farm-back.png);
    background-size: auto 110%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px !important;
```

Comment: Snippet isn't working. please provide sample html.

Comment: @SaikatRoy did you see the image? thanks

Comment: Oh ! the image you are using. that's no match with display ratio. so it'll definitely cut some section. if you make it fixed, image will be stretched.

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean by .display ratio?@SaikatRoy

Comment: I mean aspect ratio of the image. I you try to cover a 1600*900 screen with 600*400 size image. There's a ratio gap and some portion of the image will cut off.

Comment: If the image doesn’t have the same aspect ratio as its container (give or take the extra 10% that has been added and the negative margin) then it has to get cut either top and bottom or at the sides to cover OR you ask for it to be totally within the possible size and so will have blank space either at the top and bottom or the sides. What do you actually want,bearing in mind the aspect ratio of the viewport can be anything.